# no preview comes for mp4 video in ipad

Tags: ios, angularjs, html, ipad, video

```
<div ng-show="showVideo">
<video id="objvideo" ng-src="{{videoURL}}" class="col-xs-12" style="float:none" controls>
<source type="video">
</video>
</div>
```

I have the above code in my html file to show a video which has been uploaded. The problem is only in Ipad I am not getting a thumbnail preview for the video. It just shows a play button. The video plays and function perfectly, but the preview doesnt come up.

When I opened same page in chrome in my desktop and emulated Ipad , I am not able to repro.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the {{}} in ng-src

Only when you say src="{{myVar}}"

Or try removing the ng-src since you already have a source tag

Comment: I need the {{}} here, but my issue isnt that. The problem I am facing is that I am not getting a preview of the video in IPad. Any ideas related to that ?

Answer (score 0):

you should use  and remove ng-src="{{videoURL}}" from video tag and add it into source tag